# What is the meaning of big data? In sense the limit or the range beyond which can classify data as big data?

Tags: image, bigdata

I frequently hear word big data and the 4V's, volume, velocity,veracity and variety. But I don't know how to distinguish between what data can be classified as big data or not? Say for an example, I have an image, this image consists of many pixels. Can this image be classified as big data. My gut feeling is no this image is not big data, but on what logical basis can we say so?

Answer (score 0):

I think one image is not big data as it does not fulfill all 5 Vs.
In one image, data is not generated at a high speed, only unstructured for each pixel of image exists. And the value of just one image are questionable. But the one image can differ in context. What sort of value can be used based on the requirement and person considered?

Comment: I would appreciate any fine tuning to this answer, thank you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).